# Gradle skipping jacoco coverage plugin

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I know there are a lot of similar questions for this on stackexchange but this is driving me crazy and nothing from any other answers have helped me. I've used just about every force flag for gradle I can find.

My Gradle version is 2.2.1

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath("se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2")
}
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'docker'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}


ext {
  springCloudVersion = 'Dalston.RELEASE'
}

test {
  include 'src/test/java'
  finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacocoTestReport {
   reports {
     xml.enabled true
     csv.enabled false
     html.enabled false
     xml.destination "${buildDir}/jacoco"
 }  
}
dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
  }
}
```

When I run `gradle test` or `gradle clean test jacocoTestReport` or `gradle clean --re-run` etc etc I get the same results.

```
gradle test
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test UP-TO-DATE
:jacocoTestReport SKIPPED
```

I have only 1 test in the src/test/java location.

Why will it not generate the reports and run? I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the wrong include statement in your test configuration.

That seems to cause the test task to always be up-to-date (not executing any test as the include pattern isn't matched)

The `jacocoTestReport` will be skipped if there's no `execution data` available that is needed to generate the report. This `execution data` should be generated while the `test` task is executed. In your example we see that the `test` task is always marked as up-to-date (because of the invalid include statement) causing the build to never produce any input for the `jacocoTestReport` task.

Comment: Thanks! That include was "borrowed" from another example I saw and I included it without understanding why. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 1):

**For Spring 2.5 Users, who got stuck with it for hours** -*just like myself*.

I was not having the ***exec*** file generated.

And because of that ,
I found that the **jacocoTestReport** was simply "**skipped**".

**I got it fixed by adding** :

```
test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}
```

That's because I'm using **Junit5 with spring boot 2.X**

Answer (score 1):

It was a bit tricky to find that JaCoCo by default skips every `jacocoTestCoverageVerification` task in case if tests are run trough a custom named task (not just `test`).

For example, tests were run via `unitTest` in my project, JaCoCo did create `build/jacoco/unitTest.exec` during their execution, yet it kept searching for `test.exec` during verification.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

The workaround is to override `executionData` path for JaCoCo gradle tasks:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.8"
}
def coverageFile = layout -> layout.buildDirectory.file('jacoco/coverage.exec').get()
tasks.named('jacocoTestCoverageVerification') {
    getExecutionData().setFrom(files(coverageFile(layout)))
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = project.properties['testCoverageThreshold'] ?: 0.5
            }
        }
    }
}
tasks.named('jacocoTestReport') {
    getExecutionData().setFrom(files(coverageFile(layout)))
}
tasks.named('unitTest') { 
    jacoco {
        destinationFile = coverageFile(layout).asFile
    }
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport, jacocoTestCoverageVerification
}
```